# How to notify the user in MS teams when we have an incoming call from an external website embedded in the personal tab

Tags: angular, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

We have loaded an external website (which allows the user to make or recieve phone calls) as a personal tab in MS teams. The issue that we are currently facing is that when the user navigates away from the tab and comes back to the tab, the entire tab is being relaoded. We want to keep the tab active always.
Please suggest some solution/ approach to achieve the below 2 points:

1. Keep the personal tab active, even if the user navigates away from the tab.
2. How can the user be notified about the incoming calls, even if the user is not in the personal tab.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you move out from the tab and re-open the tab it, it will always reload the contents. As a workaround, you can manually pop out the chat window using the icon from your Microsoft Teams top right corner:

[image]

2. When ever you get incoming call, I think Microsoft Teams will automatically show the incoming call notification.

Comment: @Brahmajith - How did you implement the calling functionality in your external website and how are you showing it in Teams Tab ?  Can you please share the repro steps or reference doc ?

Comment: The workaround of manually pop out the window, can this be achieved using the microsft sdk?

Will share more details on the flow.

Comment: Currently it is not possible to pop-out a Tab using SDK.

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we recommend you give your new idea in Teams [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472) here.